# how can all of $e^{-x^{-2}}$'s derivatives be zero at x=0

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I recently came across the function
$e^{-x^{-2}}$
or more specifically the piecewise function
\begin{align}
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
e^{-x^{-2}} & x\neq 0 \newline
0 & x=0
\end{cases}
\end{align}
which is continuous and infinitely differentiable everywhere. I also know that $$f^{(k)}(0)=0$$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$.
however I just don't know how that could be possible. In order for the function to change surely the first derivative eventually must be non-zero, but in order for the first derivative to be non-zero surely the second derivative must eventually be non-zero, and so on until one of the derivatives are non-zero. But every derivative is zero, so my intuition tells me the function never changes, but looking at the graph it clearly does. what am I missing here?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Surely you don't have any issue with \begin{align}
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
0 & |x|<1 \\
|x|-1 & |x|\ge 1
\end{cases}
\end{align}
having the same derivatives at 0. The example shows that smooth functions display similar behavior. Maybe you would be comforted by the fact that $f^{(k)}(0)=0 $ for all $k$ **and** $f$ analytic does indeed imply that $f$ vanishes everywhere

Comment: See that $\frac{d}{dx}[e^{f(x)}] = f'(x)e^{f(x)}$. There is always the $f^{(0)}$ within the derivatives. Now, what's a trait of curves abiding $e^x$?

Comment: The simple explanation is that your intuition is wrong. Welcome to advanced analysis; this is going to happen a lot as you continue your studies. :-)

Comment: @CalvinKhor I feel like this is different from my case, since the first derivative is discontinuous, at x=1 and x=-1, the first derivative can jump to another value(1, or -1) without the second derivative increasing it. whereas in my case all the derivatives are continuous, so there shouldn't be a jump,

Comment: @JadenAmatuzzo sure, but the function is $C^\infty$ at $0$...if you want any finite number of derivatives to be good then replace $|x|-1$ with $(|x|-1)^{10000}$...Once you accept that $f(x) = e^{-1/x^2}$ has this behavior, you can also consider combining this with my example to get
\begin{align} g(x)= \begin{cases} 0 & |x|<1 \\ e^{-1/(|x|-1)^2} & |x|\ge 1 \end{cases} \end{align}
which (is smooth, and) solves $g^{(k)}(x)=0$ for all $x\in[-1,1]$, but is not zero

Comment: This function is not analytic